# Class in different namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I'm using a third party dll. I'm using a class in some namespace `namespace.class`.

In newer versions that class has been moved into another namespace so now it is `newnamespace.newpart.class`. My code needs to support both cases. How to I solve this?

Comment: Why both cases? If you need to use newer version you have to change usings in your code.

Comment: OK, you want to use the same 3rd party class, with new functional, or you're satisfied by old functional ?

Comment: I do not supply  3rd party dll. I do not know what version user has installed.

Comment: When do you have the case that it could be the old dll or the new one?
If you know it while developing your software, you could use compiler symbols to either initialize the new or the old class.

Or are you going to update just your software, and the version dll of the thirdparty app is unknown?

Comment: @cansik that is the case. I'm going to update my software and the version dll of the third-party dll is unknown.

Comment: @ShereKhan Check my answer about the late binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Develop a late binding of the 3rd party dll and check which version it is. Than you can create an new instance of the right object in the right namespace.

Here some example code:

```
//load dll
System.Reflection.Assembly myDllAssembly =
    System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("myspeciallibrary.dll");

//create object
Object MyDLLObjectInstance;

//initialize object
if (myDllAssembly.ImageRuntimeVersion == "version2")
{
    MyDLLObjectInstance = (Object)myDllAssembly.CreateInstance("MyDLLNamespace.MyDLLObject");
}
else
{
    MyDLLObjectInstance = (Object)myDllAssembly.CreateInstance("MyDLLNamespace.NewNameSpace.MyDLLObject");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more or give some links? @cansik

Comment: Thanks. I think we will try to use this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If a class exists in two namespaces, it's not the same class. It's two different classes.

There are countless ways to 'support' different classes but it depends entirely on your implementation, ie what you mean by 'support both cases'.

Comment: +1.  Personally I think the whole idea of supporting both in one "product" is faulty. :)

Comment: It exists only in one namespace, depending on the version of third-party dll installed.

Comment: @Moo-Juice yes, but I have to do that.

Comment: @ShereKhan, yes - you say you *have* to.. but can you quantify why, and perhaps we can help further?  *Why* do you *have* to do this?  If your product is dependent on a 3rd party DLL then surely you should distribute the DLL with your project and not let the customer decide?

Comment: @Moo-Juice We are unable to distribute the DLL with our project.

Comment: @ShereKhan, why?  Also - you could therefore put a caveat in "If you upgrade to our latest version of the product - you'll also have to get the latest version of SomeDamnVendorsAPI.Dll".

Answer (score 2):

My first advice would be to ensure your code-base uses the same assembly, so refactor your code so it is consistent and uses the newer version - then this whole problem goes away.

If that's not desirable, then you'll have to alias it in the files depending on what version is being used, e.g:

Legacy .cs file:

```
using ThirdPartyClass = ThirdPartyNamespace1.Class
```

Newer .cs file:

```
using ThirdPartyClass = ThirdParty.OtherNameSpace.Class
```

Note, you may run in to issues depending on the compatibility between the old and new versions.  You really should consider option 1.  And the excuse "I don't want to change it all in my code" is not an excuse (and I'm not inferring it is, just saying :) )

Comment: If they don't mean simultaneously when they say 'support both cases', this is probably the easiest and best answer.

Comment: I don't think it answers question directly, but in my opinion it would be best solution in practice. Handling cases when executive file needs to handle different dlls would be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, when your application is linking, namespace has to be known. So you can't just write app supporting two different dlls in the same way.

So after compilation there is no way to change dll.

You could try to handle your code to use **different** classes if one or another is available.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is using MEF. Write two adapter classes / MEF objects in seperate assemblies, check which third party library you have and load the appropriate adapter class.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the class is unique (i.e. it has moved completely from `namespace.class` to `namespace.newpart.class`, you could just include both namespaces...

This should compile, but at runtime if the library is swapped out it wont work...

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it does not work. It works only with library that it was compiled with.